# OSX find specific path/combination and delete

Tags: macos, shell, unix, find

I'm using OSX and would like to use the Unix 'find' command to find any instances of the following and then delete it.

/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/10.0

However, sometimes it's prefixed:

/Volumes/home/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/10.0

Othertimes:

/Volumes/Backups/_rsync-date/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/10.0

and so on...there are many other examples at various levels of the file system.

So I want to be able to find on any directory where the combination of "/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/10.0" exists and delete it.

Yes, I can use the following to delete any directory named "10.0"

```
find . -type d -name "10.0" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But I'd like this search to be more specific so I'm not deleting any folder with that name, but only folders prefixed "/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/10.0"

Your suggestions most appreciated!

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `path` predicate isn't standard, but it definitely exists on the BSD version of `find` on OS X.

```
find . -path '*/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/10.0' -type d -execdir rm -r {} +
```

The above command will match anything from the current directory down that matches that path expression *ending* in "10.0" and that is a directory itself.

Comment: this is the bomb, absolutely perfect, and elegant. I did not know of the 'path' argument. Priceless. Thank you!!!

Comment: just curious if -delete could be used instead of '-execdir rm -r {} +' ??

Comment: @Dan I doubt it. The manpage says *[-delete] will not attempt to delete a filename with a ``/'' character in its pathname relative to ``.'' for security reasons.*

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find / -name '10.0' 2> /dev/null | 
  grep 'Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/10.0$' |
  tr '\n' '\0' |
  xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Discussion points:

1. The `2> /dev/null` bit just suppresses noise from `find(1)` due to walking through a filesystem you don't have complete access to, as will be the case unless you run this as root.
2. I used the `tr(1)` after the `grep(1)` instead of `find -print0` because `grep(1)` doesn't work well with embedded nulls, so the transform has to happen after `grep` filters out incorrect partial matches.
3. Don't blindly run this command as-is. If you remove the `rm -rf` bit at the end, `xargs(1)` will just print out the paths it proposes to act on. Be sure it's going to do what you want before issuing the command as I've given it.

Answer (score -2):

```
find . -type d -name "10.0" -print0 | 
grep "Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/10.0$" | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: @WarrenYoung and the silent down-voter: Didn't see that... Changed my answer. This should work.

Comment: Nope. See point 2 in my answer for the "why".

Comment: It works fine for me as I have it here.

Comment: I don't see how. Are you trying this on an actual Mac with a file under `Application Support`? The `$` at the end of your `grep` pattern doesn't match the null characters emitted by `find -print0` instead of newline characters. Also, `grep` is going to see one big blob of matched files, rather than separate lines, so even if you remove the `$`, you still have a problem.

Comment: Now I see how it *could* appear to work. If the only directories named `10.0` are ones you want deleted *and* your version of `grep` will match the *last* item with your pattern, it will send the entire output of `find` to `xargs`. But it fails on OS X because `grep` emits a message about binary data when there are embedded nulls, and in any case it means you're potentially removing directories called `10.0` that don't have the required parentage.